# createuser: error: could not connect to database postgres,- Docker AWS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a VPC with a public subnet and a private subnet. The private subnet is has an instance for a database server. In the database server i have successfully installed docker with a postgres container. However after getting access to the bash with command :

```
docker run -it --rm postgres /bin/bash
```

I now have to create a user that i will link to a database i will create  later

```
createuser cs594user -P --createdb -h cs594db -U postgres
```

After using the command above in the bash i get the error :

```
createuser: error: could not connect to database postgres: could not translate host name "cs594db" to address: Name or service not known
```

I tested to see if the docker container was running and it was. I was able to ping the localhost successfully. I am able to access the postgres console with the command :

```
docker run -it --rm --link cs594db:postgres postgres psql -h postgres -U postgres
```

I am currently out of sorts on how to solve this issue considering this is my first time working with docker and postgres.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

After sometime reading and editing the /etc/hosts and replacing the command with the ip-address of the database server instance i was able to connect and initiate the command.
for example :

```
docker run -it --rm --link cs594db:postgres postgres psql -h 10.0.1.24 -U postgres
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot.